# Prove: $(A_1 \wedge A_2 \wedge \dots \wedge A_n) \to B\iff A_1 \to (A_2 \to (\dots \to (A_n \to B)\dots))$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I want to prove the following, using induction for every $n \geq 0$:
$$(A_1 \wedge A_2 \wedge \dots \wedge A_n) \to B\iff A_1 \to (A_2 \to (\dots \to (A_n \to B)\dots)).$$
It is an exercise regarding propositional logic. $\iff$ stands for "(tauto)logically equivalent".

My base cases for induction are (maybe I do not need all of them):

$n=0: B \iff B$ (always holds)

$n=1: A_1 \to B \iff A_1 \to B$ (always holds)

$n=2: (A_1 \wedge A_2) \to  B \iff A_1 \to (A_2 \to B) $ (proven [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXNc2.jpg), using a boolean table)

I am getting stuck at the induction step. Assuming that it holds for n:
$$((A_1 \wedge A_2 \wedge \dots \wedge A_n) \to B) \to(A_1 \to (A_2 \to (\dots \to (A_n \to B)\dots))) \text{ is always true}\\
((A_1 \wedge A_2 \wedge \dots \wedge A_n) \to B) \leftarrow (A_1 \to (A_2 \to (\dots \to (A_n \to B)\dots))) \text{ is always true}$$

I do not know why it should hold for n+1:
$$(A_1 \wedge A_2 \wedge \dots \wedge A_n \wedge A_{n+1}) \to B \iff A_1 \to (A_2 \to (\dots \to (A_n \to (A_{n+1} \to B))\dots)).$$

Any tips on how I can use the assumptions? I was also thinking about strong induction.
Tipps would be greatly appreciated before giving me a full solution. But I am glad for any input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ansatz:

$(A_1\wedge A_2\wedge\ldots \wedge A_n \wedge A_{n+1})\rightarrow B$

equivalent to

$(A_1\wedge A_2\wedge\ldots \wedge (A_n \wedge A_{n+1}))\rightarrow B$

equivalent by induction to

$A_1\rightarrow (A_2\rightarrow(\ldots\rightarrow (A_{n-1}\rightarrow ((A_n\wedge A_{n+1}\rightarrow B)...))$

equivalent by $n=2$:

$(A_n\wedge A_{n+1})\rightarrow B$ equivalent to $A_n\rightarrow (A_{n+1}\rightarrow B)$

to

$A_1\rightarrow (A_2\rightarrow(\ldots\rightarrow (A_{n-1}\rightarrow (A_n\rightarrow A_{n+1}\rightarrow B)...))$

Comment: Thank you very much! I see it now. I was thinking too much in terms of boolean tables.